# Not able to update columns in database

Tags: php, jquery

This is my userprofile.php.I have update button in this page.When I will click on this button the table will hide and form will show.But the ajax.php when i click on update profile button it will redirect me to this page without running update query in ajax.php page.

```
 <?php
      session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
       {
         include('config.php');
          include('userheader.php');
          include('usersiderbar.php');;
    ?> 
  <div id="page-wrapper">
   <div class="col-md-12 graphs">
   <div id="form4" class="xs">
 <h3><strong>Your Profile</strong></h3>
<div class="bs-example4" data-example-id="simple-responsive-table">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Phone Number</strong></th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php

     $query1=mysql_query("select * from userregister where email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");

  while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
 ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $query2['name'];?></th>
        <td><?php echo $query2['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $query2['phone'];?></td>  
      </tr>     
  <?php
  }
   ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
   </div><!-- /.table-responsive -->

    <div style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" name="upd4" id="upd4"  class="btn-success btn" value="Edit Profile" /></div>

    </div>

     </div>

     <div id='updateprofile'>

     </div>

    </div>
    </div>
  <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    <?php
    include('adminfooter.php');
    }
    else {
    $_SESSION['invalid']=='set';
    header('location:login.php');
    }
    ?>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#upd4").click(function(){

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                  $("#form4").hide();
                  $("#updateprofile").show();
                  $("#updateprofile").append(data);
                }
 });

 });

 });

  </script>
```

I am updating database but it is not showing any updation.Firstly I have user details and edit button.By clicking on edit button one form will open using ajax.

```
    <?php 
     session_start();
     include('config.php');
     $query2 = "SELECT * FROM userregister where email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
     $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
     $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

    if(isset($_POST['updatenew']))
    {

    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];

    $sql="UPDATE userregister SET name='$name',email='$email',phone='$phone' where email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<script>alert('Your Record Sucessfully Updated.');</script>";
     } 
    ?>
           <h3>Update Your Profile</h3>
             <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="horizontal-form">

                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :- </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $row2['name']; ?>" tabindex="1" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email :- </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $row2['email']; ?>" tabindex="1" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number :- </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $row2['phone']; ?>" tabindex="1" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                              <div style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn-success btn" name="updatenew" id="updatenew">Update Profile</button></div> 

                            </form>
                         </div>
             </div>
```

I have 5 columns in database but I am updating only 3 by selecting particular email id.It is showing value in input box but when i am changing the values in input box it is not showing any message .
This is my userregister.php where i have button.By clicking on that button it will show me ajax.php.

Comment: You are going to sanitize those inputs and swap `mysql_query` for mysqli or PDO, aren't you?

Comment: any errors showing?

Comment: No it is not showing any errors.

Comment: what does `$sql` actually get set to before it's executed?

Comment: I have fetch value using session but it is showing values.But when i click on update button it is not showing any message like i have used alert.

Comment: Where is input `type="submit"` to submit your form!!

Comment: ***STOP*** using `MySQL_`, if this is a school project you need to tell your tutor with some urgency that `MySQL_` is **deprecated** and they should be using `MySQLi_` or `PDO`

Comment: Okay .But what is the solution.

Comment: try, <button class="btn-success btn" name="updatenew" id="updatenew" type="submit">Update Profile</button>

Comment: Not working ,Please Help.

Comment: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check error in your page

Comment: Not Working.The problem is if(isset($_POST['updatenew']))
{  }.I have not used this thing then it was running.

Comment: use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'

Comment: And stop using mysql_* functions. stop using mysql_* functions and repeat after me stop using mysql_* functions. use PDO or mysqli

Comment: where i can use this .@ Sander Visser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add a new line in your form

```
    <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="horizontal-form">

                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                           <input type="hidden" name="updatenew" value="Update Profile" />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name :- </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $row2['name']; ?>" tabindex="1" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email :- </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $row2['email']; ?>" tabindex="1" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone Number :- </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $row2['phone']; ?>" tabindex="1" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                          <div style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn-success btn" name="updatenew" id="updatenew">Update Profile</button></div> 

                        </form>
                     </div>
         </div>

  <script>
     $(document).on("click", "#updatenew", function(){

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              $("#updateprofile").hide();
            }
  });

  });
 </script>
```

And change your button name
hope it will work for you :).

Comment: where i have to add this button.@Prateik.In ajax.php or in userregister.php.

Comment: it should be in userregister.php just after form tag

Comment: in userregister.php i have not any type of form.It is just showing data in the table.@prateik.

Comment: see i have updated the answer you should place the hidden field as i have placed in this code which is yours. :)

Comment: Thanks but i have placed the hidden button and i have changed the button name in this form.But it is not showing any results.@prateik.This is my ajax.php.So i think i will run only once.I will click on that button it is redirecting to my main page where i have ajax.

Comment: yes please so i can check for the issue i think there is still something wrong that i cant understand

Comment: Now i have published my full code.@Prateik.Ajax.php will run only once I think.So if i will click on update profile button it will redirect me to the userprofile.php page.

Comment: data: $("form").serialize().This is not sending any data but what else i can use .In ajax.php it is taking value using SESSION so it is not creating any problem.@Prateik.

Comment: you have to add one more script after the existing script for getting data i will update that script in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.@Prateik.Please Update .

Comment: you can check now.

Comment: The script you added i have paste in which page.@Prateik.and where is "updateprofile" id is used.

Comment: you can paste the script just after the script you have written for edit button click event i think its on ajax.php right?

Comment: dont put that code in $(document).ready() function make the copy of the script in separate

Comment: both button on ajax.php.The hidden one and the other ,both name will be same @Prateik.And where is updateprofile id is used.

Answer (score 0):

the button is never posted. So  `if(isset($_POST['updatenew'])) { }` will never be true

change this to the name of a mandatory field of the form. For example:  `if(isset($_POST['name'])) { }`